# What is the Mobius sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}|\mu(n)|}{n^s}$?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

It can be observed that,

$$A(s) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$$

$$B(s) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\mu(n)|}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$$

$$C(s) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\mu(n)}{n^s} = \frac{2^s+1}{2^s-1}\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$$

> **Q:** Is it true that,

$$D(s) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}|\mu(n)|}{n^s} = \frac{2^s-1}{2^s+1}\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$$
hence,
$$A(s)\,B(s) = C(s)\,D(s) = \frac{1}{\zeta(2s)}?$$

Comment: $D(s)=(1-\frac{2}{2^s}+\frac{2}{4^s}-\cdots)B(s)$ actually strikes me as more readily observed than your stated formula for $C(s)$. In fact I get a slightly different formula: $$A+C=\sum_{\substack{n~\rm sqrfree \\ \rm and~odd}}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{2^s}{2}(C-A) \quad \implies \quad C(s)=\frac{2^s+2}{2^s-2}A(s).$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is true.  Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of all positive primes.  For $T\subseteq\mathbb{P}$, write $\prod(T)$ for the product of elements in $T$.  Let $s\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\text{Re}(s)>1$.  We have
$$D(s)=\sum_{T\subseteq \mathbb{P}}\,\frac{(-1)^{\prod(T)+1}}{\big(\prod(T)\big)^s}=\sum_{T\subseteq \mathbb{P}\setminus\{2\}}\left(\frac{1}{\big(\prod(T)\big)^s}-\frac{1}{\big(2\,\prod(T)\big)^s}\right)\,.$$
Hence,
$$D(s)=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right)\,\sum_{T\subseteq \mathbb{P}\setminus\{2\}}\,\frac{1}{\big(\prod(T)\big)^s}=\frac{2^s-1}{2^s+1}\,\sum_{T\subseteq \mathbb{P}\setminus\{2\}}\left(\frac{1}{\big(\prod(T)\big)^s}+\frac{1}{\big(2\,\prod(T)\big)^s}\right)\,.$$
Therefore,
$$D(s)=\frac{2^s-1}{2^s+1}\,\sum_{T\subseteq \mathbb{P}}\,\frac{1}{\big(\prod(T)\big)^s}=\frac{2^s-1}{2^s+1}\,B(s)\,.$$

Comment: Thanks. I reckoned the other identities might be of use.